# Running multi-select variable from grafana to prometheus query

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I've a prometheus query looking like this:

```
api_latency
```

And it gives me all kinds of cool stuff, all I want to know. *To mention, it is a custom metric.*

And I can make it fetch data with some condition, like this:

```
api_latency{uri="/ping"}
api_latency{uri="/pong"}
```

I can even join them like this:

```
api_latency{uri=~"/ping|/pong"}
```

But what I want is, from the grafana dashboard, I will pickup a variable, and based on that I will execute this query. This dowpdown in grafana is a multi-select dropdown.

How can I do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it bu introducing dashboard variable with Multi-value option

Dashboard settings > Variables > <kbd>+ New variable</kbd>

- Select variable type: **Query**
- Name: as you want, in this example it will be **uri**
- Query: [`label_values(api_latency, uri)`](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/prometheus/template-variables/)
- Selection options: enable **Multi-value** (you can also enable **Include All option** if needed)

Now you'll see preview of values above the button <kbd>Apply</kbd>. And when you save changes and come back to panel, you'll see drop-down with variable in the left upper corner of dashboard.

Now you can simple use this variable in your queries, like this:

```
api_latency{uri=~"$uri"}
```

`$uri` will be automatically substituted by Grafana with `/ping|/pong` if you select those two as variables. Note that this substitution depends on data source, and it could be substituted with other format value for other data sources, more about it [here](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/dashboards/variables/add-template-variables/#add-ad-hoc-filters).

Comment: awesome, just a quick question... can I do, if `uri` has nothing selected... then show all?

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad, AFAIK, is is not possible in an elegant or recommended way. But you can use a little hack-query like this: `api_latency{uri=~"$uri"} or api_latency{nonexistent="$uri"}`